# JS, How to let a page only be loaded in another page as an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have two pages, one is `index.html` another is `iframe.html`

How to let the `iframe.html` only be loaded in `index.html`?

If iframe in `other pages` or directly type `http://www.site.com/iframe.html` in browser, the page only show some words like `opps~~something is wrong.`

something like `bing shopping`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `window.parent.location` to fetch the parent url inside the iframe and act accordingly. If window.parent is not defined it probably means that the iframe.html was called directly. If it is defined inspect the value and ensure it comes from /index.html on your domain.

Comment: @simshaun, @Darin Dimitrov, `window.parent.location` just Redirect `iframe.html` to `index.html`, but I need some effection like `bing shopping`

Comment: @yuli chika, `window.parent.location` doesn't redirects anywhere : it gives you the location of the parent hosting page (if any). If you modify the value then it will redirect. But here we are talking about reading it and based on its value acting accordingly. And by the way that's the only way for `iframe.html` to ever know anything about a parent container.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( self == top )
 location.href='/';
```

Put this in the iframe page

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it...

```
var inIframe = window.location != window.parent.location;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript in your iframe.html:

```
if (top.location.href != 'http://www.site.com/index.html') {
    // the proper redirect here
    top.location.href = 'http://www.site.com/index.html';
}
```

this way it will always be loaded as an i frame

Comment: Diallo, try to use something you give, but when open `index.html` , the page will refresh always

Comment: actually when you open index.html it shouldn't refresh, the condition is only `true` if the page is different. this code goes inside your iframe.html page not index.html